# "Suggested edit approval overridden" from 5 years ago? But nothing changed?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

It *looked like* I had a slight reputation drop (like `-2`, but I can't honestly be sure of that), so I went and had a quick look at the [reputation *tab* in my user profile](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1243/user82217?tab=reputation&sort=time).

The latest entry stated "reverted" (the tooltip reports "Suggested edit approval overridden") for the question "[Do subdomains need to be defined through domain registrar?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34076/do-subdomains-need-to-be-defined-through-domain-registrar)" but there is no reputation change shown:

[image: Reputation changes - "reverted"]

However, that would appear to be a "suggested edit" from nearly 5 years ago (31 Aug 2012) - which was approved at the time?! If you have a look at that question, nothing appears to have been rolled back (or "reverted")? The "suggested edit" is still there, although if you look at [my reputation changes for that day](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1243/user82217?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=30), it no longer reports `+2` next to that suggested edit, the reputation score is missing. (Another suggested edit a few weeks prior to this on 7 Aug 2012 shows the `+2` rep increase.)

The [Suggested Edits review queue history](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history) doesn't report any recent changes that are relevant here. **UPDATE:** However, the [original edit approval is no longer present in the suggested edit review history](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history?page=114) either.

So, what happened here?

---

Possibly unrelated, but this appears to have coincided with 4 old meta questions being "bumped to the homepage". However, these meta questions are also 5 years old!? Is there a system wide update that's digging up the past?

Comment: Possibly related on the main meta site: [Confusion about reputation activity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298104/confusion-about-reputation-activity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A long-time user deleted their account. Among other side effects, this results in the loss of any reputation earned from edits where theirs was the final vote to approve.

It appears a little bit odd in the reputation history, as the edits themselves aren't actually reverted... Still, I think it's a slight improvement over the previous behavior, wherein you'd lose reputation without *any* indicator on your profile as to what might have triggered it.

See also: [Lost reputation from suggested edit approval on post left behind when account is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249804/lost-reputation-from-suggested-edit-approval-on-post-left-behind-when-account-is)